# Opencv's "findContours" error : Thread stopped with code -1073740777

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv

I'm currently working on a program to process the datas of a 3D camera. Unfortunately i got an error using the opencv's "findcontours" function.

In fact, when i try to use it in my program i get these errors :

> Thread 0x1a4c stopped with code 0 (0x0)
>
> Thread 0x188c stopped with code -1073740777 (0xc0000417).
>
> Thread 0x1c08 stopped with code -1073740777 (0xc0000417).
>
> Thread 0x1330 stopped with code -1073740777 (0xc0000417).
>
> Thread 0x1c90 stopped with code -1073740777 (0xc0000417).
>
> Thread 0x1ed4 stopped with code -1073740777 (0xc0000417).
>
> Thread 0x10d4 stopped with code -1073740777 (0xc0000417).
>
> Thread 0x1a80 stopped with code -1073740777 (0xc0000417).
>
> Thread 0x11bc stopped with code -1073740777 (0xc0000417).
>
> Thread 0x1970 stopped with code -1073740777 (0xc0000417).
>
> Thread 0x1428 stopped with -1073740777 (0xc0000417).
>
> Program '[7932] Project_Camera.exe' stopped with code -1073740777 (0xc0000417).

Furthermore, i once got a window telling me this :

> Unhandled exception at 0xc0000417 ... (ntdll.dll). A memory segment
>   have been damaged.

( Sorry if it's not precise enough but i only remember this and didn't save what it was exactly. Plus, it's a translation of the real error cause my VS is in french so i apologize if the vocabulary is not the exact same.)

Here's my code :

```
float function (input)
{
   // First i get the datas from the camera and save it in an array of the size DATA_SIZE :
   // float distance[DATA_SIZE] (This array only contain ones and zeros)

   Mat img = Mat(Size(NB_ROW, NB_LINE), CV_32FC1, distance);

   Mat element_o = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(SIZE_OPEN, SIZE_OPEN), Point(-1, -1));
   Mat element_c = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(SIZE_CLOSE, SIZE_CLOSE), Point(-1, -1));

   Mat img_output;
   morphologyEx(img, img_output, MORPH_OPEN, element_o);

   Mat img_close;
   morphologyEx(img_output, img_close, MORPH_CLOSE, element_c);

   namedWindow("Image from morph ", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
   imshow("Image from morph ", img_close);
   waitKey(0);

   ///Convert the image into B&W CV_8U format for the findContours function
   Mat bwimg;
   img_close.convertTo(bwimg, CV_8U);

   /// Find contours
   vector<vector<Point>> contours;
   printf("here"); // I see this one 
   findContours(bwimg, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);//SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
   printf("here2"); // this one never show up, the program stops right before
   //... ( Then i get the minAreaRect from the contour and deduce an angle ) 
   return angle;
}
```

My VS solution own 2 projects :
DLLCam : where my functions are defined and built as a dll
Project_Camera : where i call the functions that are in the dll

To use opencv i built it following this link ( http://funvision.blogspot.fr/2015/11/install-opencv-visual-studio-2015.html ) to get 32 bit 3.1 version of opencv.
I correctly set up the properties of the project to use the library.

Then, i'd like to know what could cause the problem, and how i can solve it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you're probably mixing debug OpenCV libs in release, or viceversa. Also check that you're using vc14 both for compiling OpenCV libs and for your project. And that you're using static or dynamic linking according to your linked libs and project setup

Comment: First, thanks for the fast answer!
I built Release and Debug version of opencv as said in the link i gave, but i got to either in D:\opencv\build\install\include or D:\opencv\build\install\x86\vc14\lib to include or link the libraries so i guess i can't really mix debug or release versions of opencv ?
Second thing is checked, i'm using the same VS for both.
Third one : i'm linking .lib libraries, don't know if it's the correct one

Comment: Be sure that in linker -> input you put `opencv_<module>310.lib` for release, and `opencv_<module>310d.lib` for debug (note the trailing "d")

Comment: Ok ! That's something i missed. Thing is I don't have the files ending with d. Does that mean that the building of opencv failed and only gave me the files for release ?

Comment: In your tutorial there is: ` - Choose Debug and green start. 
- After that choose Release and press green start. ` It seems that you missed the debug one. Just reopen the OpenCV.sln, set to debug, and compile

Comment: BTW, it doesn't really make sense that you recompile OpenCV unless you want to use contrib modules, since there are already compiled versions available

Comment: Actually, i found the files ending with d but not in the directory \opencv\build\install\x86\vc14\lib but in \opencv\build\lib\Debug. Can i use these ones ?
In fact i couldn't find any 32 bit / x86 compiled version of 3.1 openCV, that's why i did it.

Comment: Probably yes... It seems that you just missed to compile INSTALL project in OpenCV.sln for debug

Comment: This was exactly the source of the issue. I compiled INSTALL again for debug and added the d to the library names and it worked fine. Thanks a lot for your help ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Miki said in the comments, the issue was coming from the library i was using (opencv_310.lib).

I actually missed to compile the INSTALL project of the OpenCV solution for debug. Then, the files "opencv_310**d**.lib" were missing and i coulnd't link them. 
After compiling for Debug i found those files and used them in linker -> input, thus solving the problem.